# Japanese Character Storage in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

We are storing some Japanese character in a SQL Server 2008 database through a ASP.NET UI. User submit the Excel in the tool and that Excel contains those Japanese characters. The Excel data is submitted to the backend SQL Server database.

But the database is storing the characters as

```
&#30690(semicolon)&#23822(semicolon)...
```

like this. Is there a way to convert these characters back to Japanese characters?

Thanks,

Comment: What **datatype** are your columns in SQL Server that are intended to hold those Japanese characters?

Comment: hi, the column is in NVARCHAR